# Find the nearest point of interest by latitude and longitude

Tags: gis

I have lat/long value of 180k points of interests. Now I have lat/long value of about 800k locations, what is the most efficient way to find the nearest points of interests for each of these 800k locations? Thanks!

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=efficient+nearest+neighbor+search&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart

Comment: To make it clearer, for each of the 800k locations, I'd like to find the nearest point of interest that is within a certain distance (say, within 1km radius). Now I'm thinking maybe I could round the latitude and longitude to certain number of digits so that nearby points would have the same lat/long. Not sure that's the best solution.

Comment: You could use a ball tree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree